# Link / Unlink - Vuejs Firebase - Computed doesn't work

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem in a small project I'm working on.
This project uses Firebase and Vue.js
I want to authenticate via the email address but also by Google.

However, I have a problem when I perform a "**link**" or "**unlink**", because when I do unlink, for example, my ***providerData*** object of the authUser is updated but the linkedGoogle and linkedPassword computes only work start and not when calling from link or unlink. And I do not understand how to integrate that with vuefire or firestore ...

```
unlink()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/352173/

```
linkWithPopup(provider)
```

And my variable that does not update

```
this.user = firebase.auth().currentUser
```

Comment: What do you mean by: `but the linkedGoogle and linkedPassword computes only work start and not when calling from link or unlink`

Comment: When i execute my **linkGoogle()** method, she'e execute **this.user.linkWithPopup(provider)**

This method add a object **provider** in my authUSer().currentUser of Firebase on the **providerData** object

On page load, Vue check if linkedGoogle with the computed () method, (linkedGoogle test if a **provider** named "google.com exist on my authUser().currentUser) but if i click on "unlink" method, this provider is delete.
And normaly, my linkedGoogle Computed should re-render my Component that use linkedGoogle var... but linkedGoogle work only on the page load...